# how to get value by .ajax() method in codeigniter and show the value in input field?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

sorry for ask this question again , but I still don't slove this problem!!

half years ago , I got some problem about receive value from server , and show the value in input field.

the question is below:

**when I click the button "new" , and I can get the max number from ID table.**

I write some code for this and try to use AJAX receive and show in input, it's not working,if I open the debug tools in chrome,I will get a error message :"Uncaught ReferenceError: maxnum is not defined  "

(when I only use browser to open the page /localhost/index.php/static_data/kungfu_maxquery,I can get correct json and print on screen. )

what else I can do ...... Σ( ￣□￣；)

sorry again , sorry all , I am a construction laborer , don't know too much about program code, I read the book and practice along , please teach me .

**View : （views/kungfu.php）**

```
<div class="hero-unit">
         <div style="width:250px;float:left;">
            <form id="pr_form" action="<?php echo site_url();?>/static_data/kungfu_act" method="post">
            ID：<input id="num" name="num" type="text" class="field_set"><br>
            NAME：<input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="field_set"><br>
            LOCAL：<input id="local" name="local" type="text" class="field_set"><br>
            KUNGFU：<input id="kungfu" name="kungfu" type="text" class="field_set"><br>
         </div>
         <div style="clear:both;height:50px;padding-top:10px">
            <input id="go" name="go" class="btn" type="submit" value="submit">
            <input id="query" name="query" class="btn" type="button" value="query">
            <input id="newone" name="newone" class="btn" type="button" value="new">
         </div>
      </form>
      </div>
```

**Controller（controllers/static_data.php）:**

```
class Static_data extends CI_Controller {

   public function kungfu_maxquery()
    {
        $this->load->model("pr_model");
        $data = $this->pr_model->pr_maxquery();

        echo json_encode($data);

    }
}
```

**Model（models/pr_model.php）:**

```
class Pr_model extends CI_Model {  

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('html');
        $this->load->database();
    }

   function pr_maxquery()
    {
        $this->db->select_max("num");
        $maxquery=$this->db->get("kungfu_table");
        return $maxquery;
    }
```

**JS(js/try.js):**

```
$("#newone").click(function () {

      $.ajax({
          url: "<?php echo base_url()?>/static_data/kungfu_maxquery",
          type: "POST",
          cache: "false",
          data: {'num':maxnum},
          datatype: "json",


      }).done(function () {

         $("#num").val(maxnum);

      });
  });
```

Comment: The maxnum variable in your JavaScript is undefined, that's all that means. Where are you setting it?

Comment: yes, and that's my question ..... I try to know about it and how to fix it

Comment: right, where are you setting it?

Answer (score 0):

In the data of the ajax call you are **setting** the data, not getting!!!
You should use something like this:

```
$("#newone").click(function () {

      $.ajax({
          url: "<?php echo base_url()?>/static_data/kungfu_maxquery",
          type: "POST",
          cache: "false",
          datatype: "json",
      }).done(function (result) {

         $("#num").val(result);

      });
  });
```

The function in the done recibe the result of the callback.

Comment: I think the result will be right , but how it will become meaningless code in input field , why ?

Answer (score 0):

you try like this

```
$("#newone").click(function () {

      $.ajax({
          url: "<?php echo base_url()?>/static_data/kungfu_maxquery",
          type: "POST",
          cache: "false",
          datatype: "json",
      }).done(function (resp) {
         var json = $.parseJSON(resp);
         $("#num").val(json);

      });
  });
```